# NSImageView size does not follow its window's

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, autolayout, nsimageview

I'm just playing around with OSX app dev. I'm totally noob. I thought it is straight forward like iOS app dev. But after a few days of going at this, it seems it is not that easy.

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a NSWindow. In it in which I put an Image Well (wth with the naming? lol) Well "Image Well", it is an NSImageView (no pun intended).

So I just want the NSImageView's frame to resize following the NSWindow's size. It's that simple.

Here's what I did that is NOT working:

NSImageView as imageView.

write the delegate method NSWindowDelegate method of NSWindow windowDidResize and windowDidResize: and just resize the framesize of imageView frame of the image view in it. Code: (The NSImageView is in a property called imageView.)

```
- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification {

   // NSLog(@"resized");

    NSRect zWindowRect = [[self window]frame];
    NSRect zContentRect = [[self window]contentRectForFrameRect:zWindowRect];

    [self.imageView setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(zContentRect.size.width,
                                            zContentRect.size.height)];

    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay:YES];


}
```

This method is called (tested that with `NSLog()`), however the `NSImageView` just stays there with the original size.  I checked that the `IBOutlet` connection is OK.

What gives? Why won't the `NSImageView` resize?

Comment: Ok, I tried setBounds instead of setFrame or setFrameSize, now the NSImageView changes size, but in the most weird way. When I enlarge the NSWindow, the NSImageView becomes smaller, and when I reduce the NSWindow size, the NSIMageView becomes bigger... exponentially. So, anybody knows what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. This is becoming a habit. Answering my own question again.

It seems that this behaviour is due to the "Auto Layout" feature of the Interface Builder.

To fix it, just disable "Auto Layout" in the MainMenu.xib.  [SEE HERE FOR EXPLANATIONS](http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/)

In case the site expires: just click on MainMenu.xib, then go to the first tab, File, in the Utilities panel of XCode. And there should be a "Use Auto Layout" checkbox next to it. Uncheck it.

Comment: Link to your explanation is broken.

Comment: Hence the "In case the site expires:" :D